# Create strongly typed view from code and load it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

I have a strongly typed viewpage that I created that looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.Reports.OverallResultsViewModel>" %>
```

I'm trying to create the view page in code and render it without displaying it :

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.Reports.OverallResultsViewModel> page2 = new ViewPage<Models.Reports.OverallResultsViewModel>();
```

Here is the implemented view model:

```
public class OverallResultsViewModel {
    public OverallResultsViewModel(string name, string draft, IEnumerable<Subject> subjects, IEnumerable<IResult> results) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Draft = draft;
        this.Subjects = subjects;
        this.Results = results;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Subject> Subjects { get;  set; }
    public IEnumerable<IResult> Results { get;  set; }
    public string Name { get;  set; }
    public string Draft { get;  set; }
}
```

I was thinking I'd use the following code to pass in the values to the view model:

```
page2.Model.Draft = Draft;
page2.Model.Results = page2Data;
page2.Model.Subjects = subjects;
page2.Model.Name = Name;
```

But I get an error saying that Model is null.  How do I get Model initialized so that I can set variables on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`page2.ViewData.Model = new OverallResultsViewModel(

                   Name,
Draft,
subjects,
page2Data
 );`